# Delay between animated GIF and form C#

Tags: c#, delay, gif

I guys! I have this code:

```
pictureBox9.Visible = true;
label8.Visible = true;
Form2 FL = new Form2();
FL.Show();
this.Hide();
```

`pictureBox9` is an animated loading GIF, and I want to play it like about 5 seconds and then open `Form2`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Call an async method and in it call first await Task.Delay(5); and after this call open your Form. I'm not sure if Task.Delay takes seconds or milliseconds

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I don't know how to call an async method in my code.

Comment: Drop a Timer from the toolbox onto your form.  Set its Interval property to 5000.  In your code, set its Enabled property to true.  In the Tick event handler do the rest of your snippet and set the Enabled property to false.  Do keep in mind that your user is going to get bored with it *very* quickly, especially when you waste 5 seconds of his life every single time.

Answer (score 1):

You can delay operation using:

```
await Task.Delay(5000);
```

before showing `Form2`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have to add some using system?

Comment: "The "await" operator can only be used within an async method." How can use a async method?

Comment: You call it without the await keyword. Like any other method.

Comment: Use "async" keyword in method signature. [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/hh191443.aspx) is a good sample from MSDN (how to use async/await).